# Prevent Atom Editor from auto creating files

Tags: atom-editor

at the moment I try to experiment a little bit with Atom for writing an API documentation with RAML. Everything works fine but one damn thing:
Everytime I type some file paths (e.g. `!include schemas/file.schema` Atom auto creates the file when I'm not quick enough with typing. So, in some cases I have a hole bunch of file-zombies in my schema folder. That's kind of annoying.

My setup is standard Atom on MacBook, with api-workbench plugin, which includes linter as well. I already had a look at all those settings concerning auto completion - nothing found there. Also, Google doesn't show any hints. Any Tips?

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: From a terminal can you run `apm list` and put the output in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) I strongly suspect this is a package that is adding these files.

Comment: sure, here you go: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eefd384b63d38c38ee1427bad5c279dc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a [defect in the `api-workbench` package](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-workbench/issues/162):

> Api workbench creates new schemas, while i type their paths. For example below, i can see two-three files created while i type full name:
>   E.g:
>
> ```
> schemas:
>  - myschema: !include schemas/myschema.json
> ```
>
> Will create following files:
>
> ```
> schemas/my
> schemas/mysche
> schemas/myschema
> schemas/myschemas.json - this file is existing, i've created it before. all other files are redudant and i have to delete them.
> ```
>
> Bug is not reproduced with examples, which i can also include in my document. Having issues while edition RAML 0.8 files.

If you want to help the package maintainers fix the defect, can I suggest you put together a minimal but complete example that reproduces the issue, this will make it easier for them to identify and resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, for the hint. I'll check this out. In the meantime I found a quickfix - I installed the `advanced-open-file` package. Now no files are created automatically.